# Object.assign or declared class properties?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am creating an angular application which accesses the [twitch API](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs). The data is returned in varying outlays, some of which I want to *deserialize* and store in a couple classes.

What I want to know is what are the risks of using `Object.assign` to instantiate a class compared to manually assigning properties from *deserialized* json data?

What I currently have:

```
export class UserDetails implements Serializable<UserDetails>{
    public _id: number;
    public bio: string;
    public created_at: string;
    public display_name: string;
    public email: string;
    public email_verified: boolean;
    public logo: string;
    public name: string;
    public notifications: Object;
    public partnered: boolean;
    public twitter_connected: boolean;
    public type: string;
    public updated_at: string;

    constructor() {}

    deserialize(input: any) {
        this._id = input._id;
        this.bio = input.bio;
        this.created_at = input.created_at;
        this.display_name = input.display_name;
        this.email = input.email;
        this.email_verified = input.email_verified;
        this.logo = input.logo;
        this.name = input.name;
        this.notifications = input.notifications;
        this.partnered = input.partnered;
        this.twitter_connected = input.twitter_connected;
        this.type = input.type;
        this.updated_at = input.updated_at;

        return this;
    }
}
```

What I could have using `Object.assign`.

```
export class UserDetails implements Serializable<UserDetails>{

    constructor() {}

    deserialize(input: any) {
        Object.assign(this, input);

        return this;
    }
}
```

I am about to create a new class which will have almost 70 properties.... Is this the best approach?

---

**Afterthought**... OR should I actually mix the 2 so I still get intellisense?

```
export class UserDetails implements Serializable<UserDetails>{
    public _id: number;
    public bio: string;
    public created_at: string;
    public display_name: string;
    public email: string;
    public email_verified: boolean;
    public logo: string;
    public name: string;
    public notifications: Object;
    public partnered: boolean;
    public twitter_connected: boolean;
    public type: string;
    public updated_at: string;

    constructor() {}

    deserialize(input: any) {
        Object.assign(this, input);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, having the public class level fields would be beneficial for two reasons:

1. It should provide intellisense.
2. Using any non declared field, should raise an error (this is also applicable if no field is declared). Note that using `Object.assign` can add non declared fields to the object.

Example ([fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/azg7osLc/)):

```
class Person {
  firstName;
  lastName;

  deserialize(input: any) {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }
}

let p = new Person();
p.deserialize({firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", sex:"M"});

console.log(p);     //<-- logs: Person { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', sex: 'M' }
console.log(p.sex); //<-- this logs 'M' to console in JSFiddle.
```

Note that the the propoerty `sex` is added to `p`, however, accessing the property directly like it is done in the 2nd `console.log` should raise the following compilation error (though it works on JSFiddle, not exactly sure why):

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
>
> nodesrc\test.ts (13,15): Property 'sex' does not exist on type 'Person'. (2339) ...

So if you would like to go with this kind of type-safety then declaring the fields might be helpful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *"correct tsconfig settings"*?

Comment: @Zze Please check the updated answer. The given code is raising an compilation error due to the 2nd `console.log` (expected) in my local workspace, but is working on JSFiddle. So, I thought there might be some difference in the TypeScript configuration, however, I couldn't figure out what that might be. Hopefully, the updated answer helps.

Comment: Thankyou, I will fiddle with this tonight / this weekend and get back to you.